# Migrating JSF 1.1 app to WAS7.0 results in java.lang.NullPointerException at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:144)

Tags: jsf, websphere

I have a JSF 1.1 app which was working fine in WAS 6.0 and needs to be migrated to WAS 7.0, but it results in the following exception, even though I have set `parent_last` in `deployment.xml`:

```
Uncaught init() exception created by servlet Faces Servlet in application: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:144)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)**
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You will get this exception in JSF 1.1 when the application factory cannot be found. This has in turn among others the possible cause that the `ConfigureListener` hasn't run for some reason. This is normally automatically invoked based on the `.tld` file in the JSF library. You can always try to force the webapp to run it by adding the following entry to webapp's `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

However, I don't guarantee that it will fix the problem altogether. You *may* get a different exception now which needs to be investigated and fixed separately.

WAS 7.0 ships with JSF 1.2 bundled and (well-designed) JSF 1.1 code is technically 100% compatible with JSF 1.2, so I'd rather recommend to just get rid of the JSF 1.1 libraries in your webapp and change the `faces-config.xml` to a JSF 1.2 compatible one.

Comment: We are also migrating our app which uses seam 1.1 to WAS 7.0.   Will the JSF versions cause any conflicts? It seems seam 1.1 uses JSF 1.1 and WAS 7.0 supports JSF 1.2